# How to handle a mismatch between the PUT body and URI in a REST update?

Tags: web-services, rest, http

If a `PUT` request is sent to a URI such as `http://foo.com/api/employees/123` where '123' is the employee ID, but the message body looks like this:

```
{
  "id" : 444,
  "firstname" : "John",
  "lastname" : "Doe"
}
```

How should the service handle it?

Is the expectation to update employee '123' to now become employee '444' (effectively *moving* the resource) or should it return an HTTP error response (and if so, what should it be?)

Comment: [This might interest you](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2434-http-status-codes-for-invalid-data-400-vs-422.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the id within the URI should be used and no id present in the message body. You have duplicated hints here.

The content you provide within the PUT method contains the data you want to update and it's not the case of the identifier.

Here is how I would adapt your call:

```
PUT http://foo.com/api/employees/123
(some headers like Content-Type: application/json)
{
  "firstname" : "John",
  "lastname" : "Doe"
}
```

Perhaps this link could help you: http://templth.wordpress.com/2014/12/15/designing-a-web-api/.

Hope it helps.
Thierry

Comment: Thanks, after reading the link this seems to make the most sense. There isn't a reason to require the request message to include the 'id' in it, removing the ambiguity.

Comment: Hmm this seems to violate REST principles as mentioned in https://dzone.com/articles/rest-api-path-vs-request-body-parameters

Answer (score 0):

You might use this Id according what you want to do into your put resource. Usually, id in resource uri is used to get item by id from persistence db. You can get item by uri id then you can set this id into body, but this will be odd!